# How can I disable the LED lights of a USB webcam?

Tags: webcam

I would like to disable the LED Lights on my V4L usb webcam. I would like to know if there is a generic method/way to handle that.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Maybe he is using the camera for surveillance of something legitimate, like his home, and doesn't want to tip off a burglar that there is a camera inside.

Comment: @Jakob The question is no reason to suspect someone to spy. If someone asks how `dd` works we do not suspect the person to delete my data.

Answer (score 5):

If you use linux you can use [uvcdynctrl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/uvcdynctrl.1.html)

In my case I use these commands

```
uvcdynctrl -i /usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml
uvcdynctrl -s 'LED1 Mode' 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply: you can't by software, but you can remove the LED if you have a little electrics skill.

Please note that spying your girlfriend/wife/etc. it is forbidden by law.